# Cloud9 Highlighting // TODO in comments

Tags: cloud9-ide, ace-editor, todo

I'm using Cloud9 IDE for developing a project and often I'm placing //TODO comments to remind me idea/task that I should write. Cloud9 IDE doesn't highlight the word TODO in comments and it's hard to find them in many lines of code. It's not essential for developing, but very helpful.
Is it possible to add or enable highlighting TODO in comments?

Comment: You would need to open an issue in [Ace](https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace). It's the code editing component in Cloud9.

Comment: More info on that here: http://ace.c9.io/#nav=higlighter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Ace editor was added highlighting of TODO, FIXME, XXX and HACK by nightwing.
The closed issue - https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace/issues/2181.

But I'm not sure when this feature will be in Cloud9.